# CountDistinct in Expression is adding +1 to the count SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm having trouble with an SSRS Expression. I am trying to get a distinct count of records for records that end in September.  I am using the following code:

```
=(countdistinct(IIF(Fields!dischargemonth.Value = "September" and Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!AuthId.Value, 0)))
```

The correct count should be 28. I have double checked the query and there are only 28 records, but my output results in SSRS is showing 29.

I've tried using "COUNT" but I only want the distinct count of records so that won't work. Any ideas on why this would occur?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the insight Dave. So instead of using "0", I updated the code to

```
=(countdistinct(IIF(Fields!dischargemonth.Value = "September" and Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!AuthId.Value, "Nothing")))
```

And now the count shows 28, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a count of 28 for the matching records plus a count of of 1 for the zero you are assigning for the non-matching records. Unless one of your matching records has a Fields!AuthId.Value = 0 then it would be 29. If you know that Fields!AuthId.Value will never be zero just take one off the overall result.

Comment: Hi Dave: It should be 28 records. The AuthId field will not be 0. I just don't understand why it won't count correctly.